# Cannot get editText to do a line break from enter (android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So i have multiple edittext's in one constraint layout and i cannot get my multiline edittext to do a linebreak from enter, i have tried settings imeOptions to normal, actionUnspecified, actionNone and actionDone and no luck, it does not do a line break. Could not find anyone with this issue, only opposite =)

What am i doing wrong? here is the code for my edittext

```
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text|textImeMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:ems="10"
        android:singleLine="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried android:maxLines, like  android:maxLines="10"?